# selecting a table values in other table query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have table 'printorders' :

```
id | faktor    | status
1  | 326548768 | 6
2  | 657657875 | 5
```

and I have table 'delivery' :

```
id | faktorids 
1  | 326548768-657657875
2  | 876876575-548548534
```

I want to select from delivery where faktors in faktorids all are equal to 6
and here is my query :

```
SELECT *,
       (
            SELECT status
            FROM printorders
            WHERE faktor = (SUBSTRING(faktorids, 1, 9))
            LIMIT 1
       ) AS d1,
       (
            SELECT status
            FROM printorders
            WHERE faktor = (SUBSTRING(faktorids, 11, 9))
            LIMIT 1
       ) AS d2
FROM delivery
WHERE d1= 6 AND  d2 = 6
```

but it do not work for me, where is problem?

Comment: `status ='requested'` there is no such status

Comment: thanks I edited but still not working !

Comment: when I delete ' WHERE d1= 6 AND  d2 = 6 ' ,it works and loads every record and prints d1 and d2 values !

Comment: I have a feeling you meant to write `WHERE d1= 6 OR d2 = 6` instead.. What the expected result can you make a text formatted table? "I want to select from delivery where faktors in faktorids all are equal to 6 and here is my query : "   i assume you only want factor `326548768` because thats the only one with status 6?

Answer (score -1):

> I want to select from delivery where faktors in faktorids all are
>   equal to 6

i assume you only want factor `326548768` because thats the only one with status `6`?

I believe you want this query more or less but hard to say without expected results (query not tested).

```
SELECT 
 printorders__status__6.*
FROM (     
  SELECT 
   printorders.*
  FROM 
   printorders  
  WHERE
   printorders.status = 6

) AS printorders__status__6
INNER JOIN 
 delivery
ON
 FIND_IN_SET(
    printorders__status__6.faktor
  , REPLACE(
        delivery.faktorids
      , '-'
      , ','
   )
)
```

Comment: thanks Raymond . let me explain my goal : I am working on a print center website. I store orders of users in 'printorders' table witch have a unique  column named 'faktor' and a column 'status' with value=6 for finished orders. and I have a table named 'delivery' witch stores users requests for delivering multiple orders and this table has a column named 'faktorids'  witch 9 digit faktors are stored with a dash in it. I want to select the rows of delivery requests witch all faktors are finished .

Comment: and one more thing , in my example one faktor is finished so it should return no records, but if both are finished, it should return delivery with id 1

Comment: like i said in the comments @parvaz " What's the expected result can you make a text formatted table? "

Answer (score -2):

First, you have an extra comma after d2
`) AS d2, 
FROM delivery`

Also your phrase should look a little like this

`select * from
(SELECT *,
       (
            SELECT`status
            `FROM printorders
            WHERE faktor = (SUBSTRING(faktorids, 1, 9)) AND status ='requested'
            LIMIT 1
       ) AS d1,
       (
            SELECT status
            FROM printorders
            WHERE faktor = (SUBSTRING(faktorids, 11, 9))
            LIMIT 1
       ) AS d2 
FROM delivery) main
WHERE d1= 6 AND  d2 = 6`

Comment: in fact the problem is that your status column does not exist in the main scope (delivery table) of your phrase

Comment: I was just trying to evidentiate what was wrong with the code, not write the code for him/her ;)